# Laravel - Imagick not found when a job calls it

Tags: jobs, imagick, laravel-5.5

When I call a class from a controller that uses Imagick it works just fine.
When I call the same class from a job it cannot find Imagick

using

```
$image = new \Imagick();
```

So not a namespace issue.
Any thoughts most welcome.

**EDIT:**

So this is a Mac/MAMP specific issue. Works on my production server so I am not so concerned. Both have Imagick extension installed. I suspect artisan listen is making php calls using the system version of php. I did check:`phpversion()` in my script and it is php 7.020 for both the controller and the job that has the issue. I can live with the mystery :)

Comment: you're probably using a different php.ini file for command line apps, and the imagick extension isn't being loaded by php command line. Run "php -i" to see the ini files being used.

Comment: @Danack Thank you! Your suggestion got me there. It seems even though it said the ini file was the correct one it is not the one used by MAMP Pro 4. Had to enable the extension there too and then all good. Much Thanks!!

Answer (score -1):

Laravel Don't have own Imagick Class u can't use it be default if you have own class add on app/config.php aliases if you don't have i suggest use http://image.intervention.io/getting_started/installation for image convert or crop or anything u like

Comment: Please don't answer with random stuff. If you don't know what Imagick is, just move on to another question.